# blogspot layout not showing full width

Tags: blogs, blogger, blogspot

I added a custom template to my blog but I can't edit the layout because some components are not showing properly, like below.

[image: This is my layout page]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Click "Template Tab"

[image]

2. There will be two previews of your blog page: Live on Blog and
   Mobile.
3. Click customize below "Live on Blog" preview.

[image]

4. Their you will find "Adjust Width" section
5. Enter the width value according to your need.

[image]
 6. Save

That's all.

**If you are using the Custom Template, "Adjust width" may not work. So if the above steps fail; follow below steps:(For this you should know HTML and CSS)**

1. Click template
2. Click Edit HTML
3. Find the style code of your custom template and edit with apt width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Template** then **Edit HTML** Click anywhere on your code and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd> search for **body#layout** and change the **width** property.